# on mouse hover scrolling effect

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mean-stack

I have a question is that I need an on mouse hover scrolling effect, I search more but find but only one solution is there but that was not my expectation, kindly help me out from. [Reference site](http://www.welovenoise.com/)

And I get a little [solution](http://jsfiddle.net/seler/pAu8Q/) that link is:

```
<div id="holder">
  <ul id="scroll">
    <li>Lorem ipsum.</li>
    <li>Lorem ipsum.</li>
    <li>Lorem ipsum.</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<script>
var sum = 0;
$("#scroll li").each(function() {
    sum += $(this).width() + parseInt($(this).css('paddingLeft')) + parseInt($(this).css('paddingRight'))
});
$("#scroll").css('width', sum);

$("#holder").mousemove(function(e) {
    x = -(((e.pageX - $('#scroll').position().left) / $("#holder").width()) * ($("#scroll").width() + parseInt($("#scroll").css('paddingLeft')) + parseInt($("#scroll").css('paddingRight')) - $("#holder").width()));

    $("#scroll").css({
        'marginLeft': x + 'px'
    });
});
</script>

<style>
#holder {
    background: pink;
    width: 200px;
    height: 30px;
    line-height: 30px;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-left: 100px;
}
#scroll{
    height: 30px;
    line-height: 30px;
    margin-left: 0;
    padding: 0 10px;
}
#scroll li {
    float: left;
    padding: 0 5px;
}
</style>
```

Comment: What is the problem??

Comment: on jsfiddle link just scroll left and right but i want to top and down effect also , kindly help me.

Comment: i need same effect like this http://www.welovenoise.com/, i don't know how to apply this

Comment: In your reference they are not scrolling anything.

Comment: Stark Buttowski, i need exact same effect , kindly help me